# NgModel subscribe only triggers when actual textarea is changed in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have this code below. Basically it is a component with a directive that subscribes to the model of the textarea.

If i type in the textarea, the subscribe triggers and the console log changes, however if the model is changed externally and received from the @Input in the component the subscribe in the textarea doesn't trigger, even though the text in the textarea is updating.

Why does it not trigger whenever the text is changing?

```ts
  @Directive({
      selector: 'textarea[mydir]',
      host: {'ngFormControl':'myCtrl'}
  })
  class MyDirective {
    myCtrl: any;
    constructor(){
            this.myCtrl = new Control();
            this.myCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(
            (data) => {
               console.log('Model change', data);
            });
    }
  }




  // Project card
  @Component({
    selector: 'four',
    providers: [],
    styles: [ require('./four.scss') ],
    directives: [NgFor, MyDirective],
    template: `
        Hello, this is working! <br>
        <textarea mydir [(ngModel)]="pp.status"></textarea>
    `,
  })
  export class Four {
    @Input() pp: Array<any>;
    constructor() {
    }

  }
```

Comment: @b hull, if you want a answer, it might help to add a codeden or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, it's the correct behavior. As a matter of fact, the `NgModel` directive triggers when the `update` custom event (see this line https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_model.ts#L97 in the source code) when the view is updated:

```ts
viewToModelUpdate(newValue: any): void {
  this.viewModel = newValue;
  ObservableWrapper.callEmit(this.update, newValue);
}
```

You should use a form control to implement such processing:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'four',
  directives: [MyDirective],
  template: `
    Hello, this is working! <br>
    <textarea mydir [(ngModel)]="pp.status" [ngFormControl]="myCtrl"></textarea>
  `,
})
export class Four {
  @Input() pp;

  constructor() {
    this.myCtrl = new Control();
    this.myCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log('Model change');
      });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5E4JZhm32bu8rrPV9nEf?p=preview.

**Edit**

To achieve what you expect, you need to leverage the control associated with the `ngModel` and subscribe in its `valueChanges` property. This way, you will be notified both when the value is updated in the model and from the textarea:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: 'textarea[mydir]',
})
class MyDirective {
  constructor(@Optional() public model: NgModel){
    this.model.control.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('value updated - new value = '+data);
    });
  }
}
```

I updated my plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5E4JZhm32bu8rrPV9nEf?p=preview.

Comment: i have edited my question above to use your answer, however it doesn't seem to work, can you take a look.

Comment: if I add the brackets i get this error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFormControl' since it isn't a known native property

Comment: @BHull I finally found out the solution. You must rely on the control implicitly associated with the `ngModel` and subscribe on its `valueChanges` property. Hope it fixes your issue ;-)